# In a seesaw, is it possible to consider either of the ends as the fulcrum?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum

Clasically, we learn the pivot point of the see saw as the fulcrum, and the moments are calculated as F*D, where D is the distance from the fulcrum.

However, is it possible to mentally consider one end as the fulcrum (and point of reference), and the pivot as exerting an upward force on the stick?

If so, can we calculate the upward force as (F1 + F2), and the moment as D1 * (F1 + F2)?

[image]

Comment: You mean like a lever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If so, can we calculate the upward force as (F1 + F2), and the moment
> as D1 * (F1 + F2)?

Sure you can calculate the moment about the left end due to the fulcrum, but I wouldn't call the left end a fulcrum. But to do so, the center of mass (COM) of F1 has to be located just above the left end (which it isn't in the figure). Then, if the COM of F2 were located over the right end (which it isn't in the figure), then the moment of F2 about the left end would be

$$M_{F_{2}}=F_{2}(D_{1}+D_{2})$$

Then for equilibrium

$$D_{1}(F_{1}+F_{2})=F_{2}(D_{1}+D_{2})$$

$$F_{1}D_{1}=F_{2}D_{2}$$

Which is the same equation for equilibrium when summing the moments about the fulcrum.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks a lot - the equations are extremely helpful

Answer (score 2):

Only if the system is in equilibrium (no rotation).

If there is rotation, you should use the fixed pivot as the reference point.  You can take a moving point (one end) as the reference point but have to consider the motion of the moving point in this case, since the moving point is not the center of mass.